# multiple progress bars / html5 file uploads

Tags: javascript, html, upload, xmlhttprequest

this isn't the whole code, but i think its the relevant parts. how can i make an individual progress bar created dynamically for each file dropped into a dropzone?

```
function sendFile(file) {
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (ev) {
        var bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        progressBar.value += percentComplete;
    }, false);

    dropzone.ondrop = function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        var filesArray = event.dataTransfer.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < filesArray.length; i++) {
            sendFile(filesArray[i]);
            //trigger progress bar with sendFile

            document.getElementById('file').innerHTML += '<li>' + filesArray[i].name + '&nbsp;' + '<progress id="progressBar"     value="0" max="100"></progress></div></li>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want. This isn't enough of the relevant code. What is progressBar? What is perecentComplete?  Seems like the ondrop stuff should be outside of the sendFile function but its inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I slight change in your code used jquery.

```
 function sendFile(file) {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (ev) {
            var bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
            progressBar.value += percentComplete;
        }, false);

        dropzone.ondrop = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            var filesArray = event.dataTransfer.files;
            for (var i = 0; i < filesArray.length; i++) {
                sendFile(filesArray[i]);
                //trigger progress bar with sendFile
    $('#outputlist').append('<li>'+fileArray[i].name+'   <progress  value="0" max="100"></progress></li>');

            }
        }
```

Lets come to the point you have to update the progressbars corresponding to the file names, this is a challange.

```
<progress id=fileArray[i].name value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

you can update the progressbars using file names.